# IF ELSE in where block of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1
(
    @param1 bit,
    @parma2 bit
)
AS
BEGIN 

    SELECT * from Table1 where
    if @param1 = 1 then column1 is null
    else if @parma2 = 1 then column1 is not null

END
```

Obviously the If  else part in the where clause is not correct . Could anyone suggest how to tackle it ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * from Table1 where
    case 
      when @param1 = 1 then [column 1] is null 
      when @param2 = 1 then [column 1] is not null
end
```

But you don't need two parameters for this procedure, only one should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN value ELSE value END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
Case WHEN @param1 = 1 THEN Null
Case WHEN @param2 = 1 THEN column1 Else '' End as column1 ,
* FROM Table1
```

The above statement will set column1 to null if param1 = 1, it will get the value of column1 if param2 = 1 otherwise it will set it to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the simplest option would be to use `AND` and `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE (@param1 = 1 AND column1 is null)
OR (@parma2 = 1 AND column1 is not null)
```